# Can not make post by django-tastypie to save model which has foreign key

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to save on model using POST which has foreign key. Until I set 'add', 'modify' permissions to related model it returns 401 unauthorized. 
Simple example:
models.py

```
class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    field = models.TextField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)
```

resources.py

```
class AnoterResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = AnoterModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'another'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()



class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    foreign = fields.ToOneField(AnoterResource, 'foreign_key')

    class Meta:
       queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
       authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
       allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put']
```

So, Do I need to allow 'add', 'modify' permissions for AnotherModel as well, to save MyModelResource or Did I mistake somewhere?

Comment: Closed. Details at https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/823

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to first check if you have granted proper permission to the User. For more details, please refer [this](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#authorization) link.

Also Following setup works for me. So my `models.py` looks something like:

```
class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    id = models.Integerfield()
    another_field = models.TextField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)
    mymodel_field = models.TextField()
```

and `resource.py` is as :

```
class AnotherResource(ModelResource):       
    class Meta:
        queryset = AnotherModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'another'
        authorization = Authorization()

class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    another = fields.ToOneField(AnotherResource, 'another', full=True)   
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'myresource'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Now to save any new data using `POST` on Model. I can do following `CURL` request.

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data { "mymodel_field" : "Some text value": "another" : { "id" : 1243 } }' http://localhost/api/v1/myresource/
```

Hopefully, this should help you in resolving your issue. :)